# How do I separate case ids from case values on a Discriminated Union?

Tags: f#

I want to build a dictionary from a list of items.

**An item has the following definition:**

```
type Item =
    | A of TotalPrice * Special
    | B of TotalPrice * Special
    | C of TotalPrice
    | D of TotalPrice
```

**I want the keys of the dictionary to map to the case ids:**

```
| A
| B
| C
| D
```

I would then have the values for the case id be a list.

How do I separate the case ids from the case values?

**Example:**

```
let dictionary = items |> List.map (fun item -> item) // uh...
```

**Appendix:**

```
module Checkout

(*Types*)
type UnitPrice = int
type Qty = int

type Special =
    | ThreeForOneThirty
    | TwoForFourtyFive

type TotalPrice = { UnitPrice:int ; Qty:int }

type Item =
    | A of TotalPrice * Special
    | B of TotalPrice * Special
    | C of TotalPrice
    | D of TotalPrice

(*Functions*)
let totalPrice (items:Item list) =
    let dictionary = items |> List.map (fun item -> item) // uh...
    0

(*Tests*)
open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let ``buying 2 A units, B unit, A unit = $160`` () =

    // Setup
    let items = [A ({UnitPrice=50; Qty=2} , ThreeForOneThirty)
                 B ({UnitPrice=30; Qty=1} , TwoForFourtyFive)
                 A ({UnitPrice=50; Qty=1} , ThreeForOneThirty)]

    items |> totalPrice |> should equal 160
```

Comment: And my question gets a point deduction again without me knowing why...

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted it, and I don't plan to. But I do think it's borderline downvotable, because it won't be useful to anyone else on Stack Overflow. What you're wanting to do is not a good idea in F#, and there's a better way to do it (as Fyodor Soikin already pointed out). And therefore, other people finding your question won't be helped by it. Stack Overflow downvotes are not supposed to be hostile, they're supposed to be based on "Will this question help other people?" If so, you vote it up so more people will see it. If not, you vote it down so it will be hidden.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. StackOverflow isn't meant to just serve experts of a given language. My question is completely valid for anyone that's starting off with FP. Hence, "How do I separate case ids from case values of a Discriminated Union?" I'm not the only person that is going to think of using the case id from a DU as a key for a dictionary or a lookup table. I think some of you that are advanced forgot what it was like to be a beginner.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I have added an answer just to elaborate on why you are wrong, and why the question (maybe arguably) also are wrong. You will hopefully see from some of the "necessary" transformations, how/why your data structure, to put it mildly, are not optimal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is badly defined for your use case. If you want to refer to the kinds of items by themselves, you need to define them by themselves:

```
type ItemKind = A | B | C | D

type Item = { Kind: ItemKind; Price: TotalPrice; Special: Special option }
```

Then you can easily build a dictionary of items:

```
let dictionary = items |> List.map (fun i -> i.Kind, i) |> dict
```

Although I must note that such dictionary may not be possible: if the `items` list contains several items of the same kind, some of them will not be included in the dictionary, because it can't contain multiple identical keys. Perhaps I didn't understand what kind of dictionary you're after.

Comment: I would then have the values for the case id be a list of items of that kind.

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's called a "lookup".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the dictionary with keys like A, B, C and D you will fail because A and B are constructors with type `TotalPrice * Special -> Item` and C and D are constructors of type `TotalPrice -> Item`. Dictionary would have to make a decision about type of keys.

Getting DU constructor name should be doable by reflection but is it really necessary for your case?

Maybe different type structure will be more efficient for your case, ie. Fyodor Soikin proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will clarify somewhat why datastructure and code is no good, and as such also clarify that this mainly is not related to FP as indicated in some of the comments et al.

My guess is that the question is related to "how can this be grouped", and lo and behold, there is in fact a groupBy function!

```
(*Types*)
type UnitPrice = int
type Qty = int

type Special =
    | ThreeForOneThirty
    | TwoForFourtyFive

type TotalPrice = { UnitPrice:int ; Qty:int }

type Item =
    | A of TotalPrice * Special
    | B of TotalPrice * Special
    | C of TotalPrice
    | D of TotalPrice


let items = [A ({UnitPrice=50; Qty=2} , ThreeForOneThirty)
             B ({UnitPrice=30; Qty=1} , TwoForFourtyFive)
             A ({UnitPrice=50; Qty=1} , ThreeForOneThirty)]

let speciallyStupidTransformation = 
    function 
    | ThreeForOneThirty -> 34130
    | TwoForFourtyFive -> 2445

let stupidTransformation = 
    function 
    | A (t,s) -> "A" + (s |> speciallyStupidTransformation |> string) 
    | B (t,s) -> "B" + (s |> speciallyStupidTransformation |> string)
    | C (t) -> "C"
    | D(t) -> "D"

let someGrouping = items |> List.groupBy(stupidTransformation)

val it : (string * Item list) list =


[("A34130",
    [A ({UnitPrice = 50;
         Qty = 2;},ThreeForOneThirty); A ({UnitPrice = 50;
                                           Qty = 1;},ThreeForOneThirty)]);
   ("B2445", [B ({UnitPrice = 30;
                  Qty = 1;},TwoForFourtyFive)])]
```

Yeah its still a bad idea. But its somewhat grouped uniquely, and may be misused further to aggregate some sums or whatever.

Adding some more code for that, like the following:

```
let anotherStupidTransformation =
    function
    | A(t,_) -> (t.UnitPrice, t.Qty)
    | B(t,_) -> (t.UnitPrice, t.Qty)
    | C(t) -> (t.UnitPrice, t.Qty)
    | D(t) -> (t.UnitPrice, t.Qty)

let x4y x y tp q =
   if q%x = 0 then y*q/x else tp/q*(q%x)+(q-q%x)/x*y  

let ``34130`` = x4y 3 130
let ``2445`` = x4y 2 45      

let getRealStupidTotal =
    function 
    | (s, (tp,q)) -> 
        (s|> List.ofSeq, (tp,q))
        |>  function
            | (h::t, (tp,q)) ->
                match t |> List.toArray |> System.String with 
                | "34130" -> ``34130`` tp q
                | "2445" -> ``2445`` tp q
                | _ -> tp



let totalPrice = 
    items
    |> List.groupBy(stupidTransformation)
    |> List.map(fun (i, l) -> i, 
                    l 
                    |> List.map(anotherStupidTransformation)
                    |> List.unzip
                    ||> List.fold2(fun acc e1 e2 ->
                         ((fst acc + e1) * e2, snd acc + e2)  ) (0,0))
    |> List.map(getRealStupidTotal)
    |> List.sum

val totalPrice : int = 160
```

might or might not yield some test cases correct.

For the above testdata as far as I can read the initial code at least is ok. The sum does get to be 160...

Would I use this code anywhere? Nope.

Is it readable? Nope.

Is it fixable? Not without changing the way the data are structured to avoid several of the <strike>stupid</strike> transformations...